# Mezzanine 3.1.10 (Django CMS): Can't delete media files in the admin page

Tags: django, content-management-system, mezzanine

I'm using the newest version of Mezzanine as my website CMS. The error always occurs when I click the trash can icon. Is there any way to find out what's going wrong or anything suggested that I can check to solve this error?

[image: Error Page Looks Like This]

Comment: By the way, I just want to delete the .ppt file.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you might check:
1. if the file was created by another user, perhaps you have to be that user to delete it
2. similarly, if it was associated with another site, you might have to delete if from within the original site.
Beyond that it's manual database stuff. Good luck!